# Conditional formatting on a value of "?"

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional coloring using VBA. I am using Windows 7 and Excel 2010. My rules work well with the exception when the value in the cell is a single question mark `?`.  It seems as if the question mark is evaluated as the single character wild card in a regular expression, which causes all cells in the selected range to highlight. When I use the menus (not VBA) to set the rule all works well. I have tried to capture the rule recording a macro of the rule setting and using it in my VBA code, but it doesn't work, exhibiting the all cell highlighting above when the VBAa runs.

Is there a way to write the rule to highlight cells for the value of a single `?`?

Comment: Please format your question correctly. Wallsoftextarehardtoread as you can see in the example provided.

Comment: Add your current code to the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
With Range("A1:A8").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""?""").Interior
  .ColorIndex = 3
End With
```

The above applies conditional coloring to cells having a value being equal to a single question mark.

Comment: Thanks so much. As this solution looked so similar to the recorded macro generated code, I tried to record the macro for conditional formatting on another machine (than that on which I had the problem) and it worked. I need to investigate why there is a difference. Thanks again for the rapid response.